# How to have minimized images a separate 'assets' folder using ImageMinimizerWebpackPlugin

Tags: webpack, image-compression

I was able to shrink images using ImageMinimizerWebpackPlugin however I want them to be in a separate 'assets' folder inside public

[image]

How can I go about doing it ?

providing related snippets only

```
    module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|webp)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: ImageMinimizerPlugin.loader,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

 optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      "...",
      new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
        minimizer: {
          implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
          options: {
            // Lossless optimization with custom option
            // Feel free to experiment with options for better result for you
            plugins: [
              ["gifsicle", { interlaced: true }],
              ["jpegtran", { progressive: true }],
              ["optipng", { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
            ],
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

*Webpack 5.x*, the [output.assetModuleFilename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputassetmodulefilename) option can help to emit assets to a specified directory.

Example:

project structure:

```bash
✗ tree -L 3 -I 'node_modules'
.
├── dist
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── 76187f0cb2410e638364.jpg
│   ├── index.html
│   └── main.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── images
│   │   └── workflow.jpg
│   ├── index.html
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require("image-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[hash][ext][query]',
    clean: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      "...",
      new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
        minimizer: {
          implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
          options: {
            plugins: [
              ["gifsicle", { interlaced: true }],
              ["jpegtran", { progressive: true }],
              ["optipng", { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
            ],
          },
        },
        loader: false
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
import workflow from './images/workflow.jpg';

function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = workflow;
  element.appendChild(image);
  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.8.2",
    "imagemin": "^8.0.1",
    "imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
    "imagemin-jpegtran": "^7.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^10.0.1",
    "serve": "^14.2.0",
    "webpack": "^5.80.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help  output.assetModuleFilename option is new to me should read its documentation now .... I used loader since wasn't able to minimize images without it ...
I should try to run your snippets too